# sql server - move tables from master to new database

Tags: sql-server-2005

In an attempt to move my DB to a new server I had to run the script from cmd prompt and forgot to assign the DB name and all my tables were created under master. Is it possible to move these tables to a different DB or do I need to rerun the script?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You would need to rerun the script.

There is no way to move tables between databases.

Comment: +1, @vbNewbie, you already have a working script, just re-run it.  Make sure you drop all the junk you added to master though

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you just create the new database, create the tables, insert rows from tables in Master to your database, then drop the Master tables?